# Java compare specific parts of a string

Tags: java, string, split

I got some entries in a database of files with a specific naming pattern e.g.:

Filename1: abc_01234xyz_001_000_009

Filename2:
abc_45678xyz_002_004_012

The part after abc_ for example 01234xyz is the name of the specific file and the last 3 digits are the version

Now I have a different database where there might be the same file or a older version of it e.g

abc_01234xyz_001_000_008

Is given in this example it's the same file but an older version, in this case the older file can be deleted

Now my question is is there a practical way to compare those files?

Or is the only way splitting these strings for example by "_" and compare the indexes (here index 1 and 4)?
The files have the same naming pattern with the seperation by _

Comment: So you first need to group them by their common name tokens. Then once you have the group, you can decide the fate of each member of the group

Answer (score 0):

I will address the Java route, which seems to be the focus of your question. But you *can* do this work on the database, in SQL; see [Answer by phatfingers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901147/642706).

## Java

### String manipulation

Yes, you could do that by manipulating strings. Do that if all you need is a one-and-done quick-and-dirty solution.

## Objects

Instead of string manipulation, you could use objects. Go the [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) way if you will be doing much work with these files.

Write a class to represent the meaningful fields embedded in your text.

I would use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) as the main purpose of this class is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You can define a record locally, if you want.

```
record File ( … , String name , … , int version ) {}
```

Add a static factory method taking your input string as an argument. Split the input string on your underscore delimiter. Parse each element of that split. Pass those parsed values to the constructor of our record. Return the new `File` record object.

Mark your record as implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Write the necessary `compareTo` method using your logic of sorting by name primarily and then version secondarily.

Define a navigable/sorted map of the type `NavigableMap < String , List < File > >` where string is the `name` field of our record. Populate the map using a sorted list or a `SortedSet`/`NavigableSet`. With this map you can see review all your files. And you can see which have multiple versions, with multiple entries in the list of `File` objects. The last of each list is thi most recent.

Add an instance method `toFileSystemName` to recreate the original full name of the input. You’ll need this when you go to delete a file.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL

You could eliminate them in the database using a SQL statement.  Since your version format is organized such that the newer version is always alphabetically larger than a prior version, and is always the same length, it facilitates a simple string match.

Your file name can be matched by `LEFT(filename, LENGTH(filename)-11)`

Your version can be matched by `RIGHT(filename, 11)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_used_for_deletion FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
  ON LEFT(t1.filename, LENGTH(t1.filename)-11)=LEFT(t2.filename, LENGTH(t2.filename)-11)
  WHERE RIGHT(t1.filename, 11) < RIGHT(t2.filename, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can definitely compare the files.

I recommend creating a class, call it `Version`, to hold the values.
Then create a method to compare it to another version.

The `parse` method here, requires just the version portion of the filename, not the entire filename.
The `compareTo` works similar to a `String.compareTo`, where it will return `-1` if it is less-than the parameter value, `0` if it is equal, or `1` if it is greater-than.
The `toString` is simply for debugging purposes.

```java
class Version {
    int major, minor, build;

    static Version parse(String string) {
        String[] strings = string.split("_");
        Version version = new Version();
        version.major = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
        version.minor = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
        version.build = Integer.parseInt(strings[2]);
        return version;
    }

    int compareTo(Version version) {
        if (major > version.major) return 1;
        else if (major < version.major) return -1;
        else {
            if (minor > version.minor) return 1;
            else if (minor < version.minor) return -1;
            else {
                if (build > version.build) return 1;
                else if (build < version.build) return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%d.%d.%d".formatted(major, minor, build);
    }
}
```

You could then utilize this method, possibly as a field within a class, or just as a way to compare the values against other values.

Here is an example, using your data.

```java
String fileA = "abc_01234xyz_001_000_009";
String fileB = "abc_45678xyz_002_004_012";
String nameA = fileA.substring(0, fileA.length() - 12);
String nameB = fileB.substring(0, fileB.length() - 12);
Version versionA = Version.parse(fileA.substring(fileA.length() - 11));
Version versionB = Version.parse(fileB.substring(fileB.length() - 11));
System.out.println("nameA = " + nameA);
System.out.println("nameB = " + nameB);
System.out.println("versionA = " + versionA);
System.out.println("versionB = " + versionB);
System.out.printf("%s compare %s == %d%n", versionA, versionB, versionA.compareTo(versionB));
```

Output

```
nameA = abc_01234xyz
nameB = abc_45678xyz
versionA = 1.0.9
versionB = 2.4.12
1.0.9 compare 2.4.12 == -1
```